# How can I use substitude within `geom_textabline`'s label?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `substitute` to substitute some values into the label text of `geom_textabline`. However, it is constantly giving me the following error:

> Error in `check_aesthetics()`: ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or
> the same as the data (1): label

I tried to convert the expression in the label to characters, or use paste to join etc. but none worked.

How can I use substitude within `geom_textabline`'s label?

```
dSlope <- 2
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=cyl)) +
  #facet_wrap(Y~., scales = "free")+ 
  geom_textabline(label = substitute("r = -("*x~ frac(mu*m,s)*") t", list(x = sprintf("%.3f", abs(dSlope))))
                  , slope = dSlope, intercept = 0
                  , size = 0.36*fontSize, color = "black", hjust = 0.8, vjust = -0.2, show.legend = FALSE, parse = TRUE)
gg
```

Note: the above code is a simplied versions of a larger and more complicated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label generated by `substitute` is being interpreted as having length 3. A workaround is to `deparse` the substitute and use `parse = TRUE`:

```r
library(geomtextpath)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

dSlope <- 2
fontSize <- 16

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_textabline(label = deparse(substitute("r = -("*x~ frac(mu*m,s)*") t", 
                                     list(x = sprintf("%.3f", abs(dSlope))))),
                  slope = dSlope, intercept = 0,
                  size = 0.36*fontSize, color = "black", parse = TRUE,
                  hjust = 0.4, vjust = -0.2, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you figure out the fact that "`substitute` was being interpreted as having length 3" ?

Comment: I wrote `geom_textabline`, so I figured what the problem might be. I confirmed it by checking `length(substitute("r = -("*x~ frac(mu*m,s)*") t", 
                                     list(x = sprintf("%.3f", abs(dSlope)))))`